# How do I search for a string and put it in a variable in shell script?

Tags: shell, sed, grep

just wondering if anyone could help me. I have a file containing a line:

```
W32i   APP   -     8.0.0.xxxxx shp 6SFE25~1.EXE
```

xxxxx are 5 digit numbers and the numbers are different for everytime. I want to be able to search for xxxxx and put it in a variable, so I can use this varibale. Do I use grep and sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a.txt

```
W32i   APP   -     8.0.0.xxxxx shp 6SFE25~1.EXE
```

code

```
 num=$(< a.txt)
 num=${num#*.0.0.}  # "left" remove everything up to .0.0.
 num=${num%% *}     # "right" remove "all" after " " char
 echo "num=${num}"
```

output
     xxxxx

You'll be glad that you spend time to understand the difference in how variable modifiers like `${num#xxx}, ${num##xx}, ${num%x}, ${num%%x}` work. Advanced shells also support `sed` like substitutions, `${num/0/9}` and `${num//0/9}`.

IHTH

Comment: It works! The comment really helps me learn, thank you so much! :)

Comment: To see the difference between the `%` and `%%` modifier, this code is a good example, i.e. only using `%` results in `xxxxx shp`, because the deletion starts at the right, finds the first ' ', and deletes to the end. With `%%`, the deleteion starts at the right, but then looks for all ' ' (moving to the right), and then deletes everything to the right, leaving only `xxxxx`. Good luck to all.

Comment: I was about to ask you the differences, and you've just explained it! Thank you so much for your detailed explaination. This is a great help for newbies like me :) xxx

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

read < a.txt
[[ $REPLY =~ 8.0.0.([^\ ]*) ]]
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

output

```
xxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'm/(\d{5})/g;print $1'
```

tested [here](http://ideone.com/iwXWXp)